# Pulling list of several ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm putting together a 'User Profile' page, and would like to list their most recent 5 comments. The problem is, I have several comment tables for several different objects. For example, I have three tables: sports_comments, game_comments, and foobar_comments. I want to get a list of the last 5 comments between the three tables. What is the best way to accomplish this, either in the controller or in the view? Each comment table has a user_id, and the user has_many of all three. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd argue that perhaps you shouldn't have three different tables for comments.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - I'd then ask how you'd think I should go about it!

Comment: Use a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) and then you'd only have one table of comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) if the differences between these comments are not so high...

...but pay attention if you rely on [record identification](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification#relying-on-record-identification) for subclasses, you need to declare the subclasses too as resources to work.